# Adding to profile.local in Ubuntu?

Tags: path

I was told to adjust the `/etc/profile.local` with following lines
(as user root):

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/cmds:.
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/lib
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:~/lib
export ALLOW=1
```

But I can't seem to find a `profile.local` file, I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. In any case, the program I need to do this for is looking for a command in `cmds`, so I assume this is just updating my path?

I'm fairly new to Linux, so any help would be appreciated. I tried updating the global `/etc/profile`, but this did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/etc/profile.local` is not present then you can simple create it and write those lines in any text editor or simple copy and paste this one:

```
cat <<EOF>/etc/profile.local
export PATH=$PATH:~/cmds:.
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/lib
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:~/lib
export ALLOW=1
EOF
```

The reason why you were told to put it into `/etc/profile.local` is that this file will not be overwritten whereas `/etc/profile` would be updated when you system is updated.

Comment: There is only one etc file, right? Not one per user?

Comment: There is only one /etc/profile.local for whole system. But those line which update `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and set `ALLOW` variable will affect all users in the sense that all of them can have `~/cmds` folder in _their own $HOME directory with their own executables_.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the method described in [@jimmij's answer regarding `/etc/profile.local`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159926/7453), changes such as this can be placed in a file under `/etc/profile.d` too.

Files in this directory are sourced when accounts login. For example:

```
$ ls -l /etc/profile.d/ | head -5
total 120
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  771 Mar 26  2014 256term.csh
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  841 Mar 26  2014 256term.sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2864 Apr 23 04:28 autojump.bash
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  619 Apr 23 04:28 autojump.sh
```

These files would be sourced when users logged in using any bourne style shells such as `zsh` or `bash`, or a `csh`.

These files simply would contain your exports like so:

```
$ more /etc/profile.d/lithograph_software.sh
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/cmds:.
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/lib
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/lib
export ALLOW=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the same problem and didn't find anywhere this simple solution. After creating `/etc/profile.local` file by adding custom commands You should add next string in user `.profile` file

```
test -s /etc/profile.local && . /etc/profile.local
```

For all users you have 2 situations:

1. If user doesn't exist add this line to

   ```
   /etc/skel/.profile
   ```

   SKEL directory can be missed by default if your user already have `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` files. And it don't work for existing users.
2. For existing users (if this is root for example) you should add it manually to `/root/.profile` or for other user to `~/.profile` or  `~/.bash_profile`. And re-login after this step.

This advice is suitable for such OS as Ubuntu. Other OS can have this built-in solution. For example SUSE Linux.